# NodeJs execute command in background and forget

Tags: node.js

I have an endless NodeJS `script.js` loop and I need this script to execute another script in background as a service which is a WebSocket service actually.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('node bgService.js &');
```

So now both scripts are running okay!

When I do a `Ctrl+C` on my `script.js`, the `bgService.js` script is also removed from memory which I don't want to.

How to run something in the background and forget ?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can do it using [child_process.spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) with `detached` option:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('node', ['bgService.js'], {
    detached: true
});
```

It will make child process the leader of a new process group, so it'll continue running after parent process will exit.

But by default parent process will wait for the detached child to exit, and it'll also listen for its `stdio`. To completely detach child process from the parent you should:

- detach child's `stdio` from the parent process, piping it to some file or to `/dev/null`
- remove child process from the parent event loop reference count using `unref()` method

Here is an example of doing it:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('node', ['bgService.js'], {
    stdio: 'ignore', // piping all stdio to /dev/null
    detached: true
}).unref();
```

If you don't want to loose child's `stdin` output, you may pipe it to some log file:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    out = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a'),
    err = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a');

spawn('node', ['bgService.js'], {
    stdio: [ 'ignore', out, err ], // piping stdout and stderr to out.log
    detached: true
}).unref();
```

For more information see [`child_process.spawn` documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)

Comment: Is it possible to write the process id to a file?

Comment: @chovy sure. `spawn` returns an instance of [ChildProcess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess) class, containing, among other things, [pid](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_pid). of a spawned process

Comment: `fs.writeFileSync(pidFile, \`${ff.pid}\n\`, 'utf8');`

Comment: @chovy yes, that's the idea. But please, don't use ES6 syntax in non-ES6 questions, since it may confuse people.

Comment: `fs.writeFileSync(pidFile, ff.pid+'\n', 'utf8');` es5

Comment: the out / err is syntax invalid now in node:20, it has to be a stream such as writeStream

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: (tl;dr)

```js
spawn('command', ['arg', ...],
  { stdio: 'ignore', detached: true }).unref()
```

`unref` is required to prevent parent from waiting.

[docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)