# How to start monetdbd from other process (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, monetdb

I'm trying to start monetdbd from node like

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('monetdbd start ~/my-dbfarm/');
```

But it stops runing my code after `exec(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
nohup monetdbd start ~/my-dbfarm/ &
```

'nohup' indicates that if the owner hangs up, it will still run

'&' indicates that the process should run in the background

if that doesn't work take a look at:

[NodeJs execute command in background and forget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323703/nodejs-execute-command-in-background-and-forget)