# Node.js create "weak callback" that doesn't prevent process from exiting

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Is it possible to create a "weak callback" (by analogy with "weak reference") that doesn't prevent node.js from exiting? I'd like to be able to define an "optional handler" for a long-running asynchronous task that will get executed if the node.js process is still running, but doesn't prevent the event queue from being considered "empty" by itself. I don't have a real world use case for such a construction, I'm just wondering if node.js supports it (it might require a native extension).

Here's a really simple program that calls `/bin/sh -c "sleep 9 ; ls"` and waits for it to finish. The node.js process is basically idle for 9 second until the child process finishes.

```
var child_process = require("child_process");

child_process.exec("sleep 9 ; ls", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
console.log("end");
```

I'd like to be able to write something like this, where I'm using `setTimeout` to create a non-weak callback so the program is guaranteed to stay alive for at least three seconds. (Note: `child_process.exec` does have a timeout option, but that has to be set in advance, whereas this approach allows the deadline to be changed after the fact)

```
var child_process = require("child_process");

child_process.exec_weakly("sleep 9 ; ls", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
setTimeout(function() {}, 3000); // prevent exit for at least three seconds

console.log("end");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of timers you can use [unref](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timeout_unref) function like this:

```
 let timer = setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('tick');
 }, 3000);
 timer.unref();
```

Looks like you can [do the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323703/nodejs-execute-command-in-background-and-forget) for `child_process.spawn`.