# How can a NodeJS app restart itself as sudo?

Tags: node.js

I've got a NodeJS app that needs to run as superuser.  The user running this (should) have sudo privileges.  Therefore they can easily run the app with "sudo node ...".  For convenience, I would like the app to restart itself with sudo if it's not running as root.

Reading [NodeJs execute command in background and forget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323703/nodejs-execute-command-in-background-and-forget), I have tried the following:

```
const isroot = process.getuid && process.getuid() === 0;
if (!isroot) {
  console.log("Must be running as superuser! Restarting with sudo.");

  spawn("sudo", process.argv, {
    stdio: "inherit",
    detached: true
  }).unref();

  process.exit(0);
}
```

However, this doesn't work as the user needs to enter their password and, despite setting stdio to inherit, I get the error:

```
  sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, and is there a more obvious solution?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: So in other words _"how can I run my app with superuser permissions without actually being authorised by a superuser"_ - you understand why you can't do this, right? Also, tbh this is off-topic as it's not really a Node issue.

Comment: They woud be authorised as superuser, as they would have sudo permissions, and I want it to ask for a password.  This is no different to typing "sudo node ..." which is allowed.  I don't see the difference.  I just want to make it a bit more convenient, so if you run it with "node ..." you don't need to rerun it with "sudo node ...".  How is this a security issue if you've got sudo permissions?

Comment: Regarding whether it's a node issue, I can (and do) do the same thing in a bash shell script with *if [ "$(id -un)" != "root" ]; then echo "Need root - sudoing..."; exec sudo "$0" "$@"; fi* I want to know how to do the same thing in Node.  Therefore I think it is directly a node question.