# Run a python Script from an Angularjs Web Application

Tags: angular, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a web application written in angular.js and I've a python script `run.py` saved in my downloads directory, which is the sane directory as the app.

When I start the app in the working directory, which is also the directory that has the python script, I want the app to execute `run.py`. This should happen everytime the app is started/initialized. How can I achieve this? Is this achievable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJs execute command in background and forget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323703/nodejs-execute-command-in-background-and-forget) You should be able to launch your script as part of your webserver startup code in a subprocess.

Comment: Is the app in the same directory? If not, how should it know where the script is - will the path be hard-coded, for example? Or do you want to use the fact that the script is in the current working directory? Anyway, this is not a Python question, and `run.sh` is a strange name for a Python script (it makes it look like it should be a shell script instead).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, the app is in the same directory. I want ti use the fact that the script is in the current working directory. I have corrected the file name, it was a mistake on my path.